# How does periodicity checking in the Mandelbrot Set work?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-dynamics

I was going through the Wikipedia page, on how periodicity checking works in the bulbs of the Mandelbrot Set. I do not understand why the code stores of a new `x` and `y` value every 20th iteration. Isn't this **not useful**, when the period of a bulb is more than `20` ?

Here is the link to the wikipedia page:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotting_algorithms_for_the_Mandelbrot_set

Comment: From the same page : "The above code stores away a new x and y value on every 20:th iteration, thus it can detect periods that are up to 20 points long. "

Comment: I think the point is that if you try to check for very long periods, you will get a lot of false positives unless your accuracy is very high. Period 20 is already a lot (there are about 2^20 bulbs of period 20).

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Suppose, if my number of iterations is say a **1000** , then since I start iterating at (0, 0), why can't I check whether I hit (0, 0) at some **i-th** iteration and break my loop? I found that my idea does not work. But, can you please explain why?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki there are about 2^19 components of period 20, but the vast majority are cardioid-like, and only 561 are circle-like bulbs.  Ref: https://mrob.com/pub/muency/enumerationoffeatures.html

Comment: @VivekanandV only the centers of components are exactly periodic with $0+0i$ in their limit cycle.  Orbits of other points inside components approach limit cycles that don't contain $0+0i$, for example with $c=-0.5$ the orbit approaches the fixed point $z_\infty = -0.3660254037844386\ldots$.

Comment: @Claude Thankyou for your reply. I understand now. Therefore you need a fair amount of accuracy initially, to conclude that periodicity is working. This accuracy can only be obtained after a certain number of iterations, and therefore we need to store off new ```x``` and ```y``` values after our checking period of 20, and then again continue our **search**. Am I correct ? Also, being a newbie to all this can you please tell me what does the term *component* mean ? And also, how do you know there are $2^{19}$ components?